# How can I update my inputs with PATCH in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, rest, crud, angular-reactive-forms

I have developed a form with Reactive Forms and would like to overwrite the content of the input with a new value. I would like to send the mandantKagId from the JSON so that an update can take place. Do you know how this works?

Here is my code:

```
// Snippet from JSON
 {
            "accountlinevaluesId": 1,
            "accountlineId": 1,
            "mandantKagId": 660, 
            "mandantAccountsId": 1, 
            "period": "7",
            "accountNumber": 27,
            "name": "EDV-Hardware/Software",
            "amount": 55.16859,
            "mandantKagAccountEntity": {
                "mandantKagId": 660, // I want to send this
                "mandantId": 1,
                "kagNumber": "2000",
                "kagText": "A. I. 1. EDV-Software"
            }
```

```
// Service
 // To change entries
  changeEntries(balanceListChanges: BalanceList): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.patch<any>(`${environment.baseUrl}/changekag`, balanceListChanges, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    }).pipe(map(data => data));
  }
}
```

```
// TS

 // To change entries in the BalanceList
  changeBalanceList() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // Stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.balanceListForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.balanceListService.changeBalanceListEntries(this.balanceListForm.value)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log('Response:', JSON.stringify(data));
          this.submitted = false; });
      }
```

Comment: Did you try `patchValue` on your `FormGroup` (I guess `balanceListForm`)? https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model

Comment: No, I work with FormArray. But what is the use of patchValue in my use case? I have already written the service... I would like to know how I can send the clientKagId from the Json to the backend. Think that you can update the inputs

Comment: Ahaa, when you said input, I associated to an `<input>`, and thought that the question is somehow about the forms. But then sorry, I still don't get the problem. I mean, you just parse the json with `JSON.parse` and `parsedObject.mandantKagAccountEntity. mandantKagId` but that's probably not what you ask.